# How to call a second AsyncTask task after the first AsyncTask has been completed but dismissing progress dialog is crashing the app

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have two AsyncTasks, where the first AsyncTask shows a Progress Dialog does some stuff in doInBackground, and when it comes to onPostExecute, I am dismissing the progressDialog and executing my second AsyncTask but the app crashes. If I don't call my second AsyncTask the progress dialog dismisses fine but as soon as I execute my second AsyncTask the app crashes on me.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void... params) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    //Then calling second AsyncTask

}
```

I need to call the second AsyncTask after the first AsyncTask has been completed, because the second AsyncTask uses data after the first AsyncTask has been completed. I thought the best way to do this is to dismiss the Progress Dialog so the user can carry on using the app and in the background the second AsyncTask can go on and do its background work?

Is it possible to dismiss the ProgressDialog and call the second AsyncTask as well?

Thanks.

Comment: please post the logcat :)

Comment: Whether in onCreate() or any other place, wherever you are specifying to start your AysncTask1, you can call the second AsyncTask there, if both are not related. It also might be the case that something in your second AsyncTas is causing the error.

Comment: Hi guys, I did not even think about looking at the logcat. After looking at the logcat it was clear that some errors were thrown in the second AsyncTask. Once I fixed the errors it worked fine. Does any one of you want to put that down as an answer which I will accept to close this question? Thanks both for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by Shobhit Puri as a comment above:

Whether in onCreate() or any other place, wherever you are specifying to start your AysncTask1, you can call the second AsyncTask there, if both are not related. It also might be the case that something in your second AsyncTas is causing the error.